# What is a Scheming Word™?

Tags: pattern, enigmatic-puzzle, calculation-puzzle, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a ***Scheming Word™***.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Scheming Words™ | Not Scheming Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ALIENIST | NATURALIST |
| AREAR | FORWARD |
| CARVERY* | CHURRASCARIA |
| CHASTER | CHASER |
| FISHIEST | FRANKEST |
| HARSHER* | GENTLER |
| HEH* | MEH |
| PEP* | POP |
| RACECAR* | REVIVER |
| REAR | FRONT |
| SHAVEN | SHAGGY |
| TEAT | BOSOM |
| YEATSIAN | KEYNESIAN |

*** These are Naturally Scheming Words™**

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Scheming Words™,Not Scheming Words™
ALIENIST,NATURALIST
AREAR,FORWARD
CARVERY*,CHURRASCARIA
CHASTER,CHASER
FISHIEST,FRANKEST
HARSHER*,GENTLER
HEH*,MEH
PEP*,POP
RACECAR*,REVIVER
REAR,FRONT
SHAVEN,SHAGGY
TEAT,BOSOM
YEATSIAN,KEYNESIAN
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Scheming Word™ without relying on the other words.

**What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: Shouldn't *Rubio* be on the list?

Comment: @n_palum and with a star too!

Comment: I'm not very good at this, but here are some of my thoughts: 
None of the Scheming Words have the letters 'o' or 'u'.
 There are sentence schemes which you can read about [here](https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/schemes.html) and also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme). They don't really apply to individual words, but the general patterns in there could be adjusted. 
Many of the Scheming Words allow you to remove a letter to make a different word, but not all (this is probably nothing). There is an 'e' in every Scheming Word. Almost every Scheming Word has E between two repeated letters

Comment: I'm drawn to the fact that two Scheming words have the pattern 'EAR' in them and two have the pattern 'EAT'.

Comment: There's got to be something to do with the letters that are being used? All the scheming use just over half the letters in the alphabet, and the one word on the non-scheming side that _only_ uses those same letters is *Chaser*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How to work out a Scheming Word™:

> Scheming refers to the synonym of *calculating*. Notice every single scheming word has **ONE** letter `E`. The letter `E` refers to `Equals`, or `=`, `A` refers to `Add` or `+`, and `S` refers to `Subtract` or `-`. The other letters refer to their numerical value in the alphabet. *Naturally* scheming means you don't have to attach a `+` or a `-` to a following number to make it work

Full list:

> ALIENIST - `+129 = 149 - 20`
>  AREAR - `+18 = +18`
>  CARVERY - `3 + 1822 = 1825`
>  CHASTER - `38 + -20 = 18`
>  FISHIEST - `69 - 89 = -20`
>  HARSHER - `8 + 18 - 8 = 18`
>  HEH - `8 = 8`
>  PEP - `16 = 16`
>  RACECAR - `18 + 3 = 3 + 18`
>  REAR - `18 = +18`
>  SHAVEN - `-8 + 22 = 14`
>  TEAT - `20 = +20`
>  YEATSIAN - `25 = +20 - 9 + 14`

Comment: [rot13](www.rot13.com):Gur erfg bs gur yrggref frrz gb or N1M26 va onfr gra (gung vf, YV rdhnyf Y gvzrf gra cyhf V)

Comment: @Rubio Is that a better description? I was looking at it and noticing CARVERY didn't fit with my explanation either.

Comment: That's got it now. Nicely done, I'm so glad this was solved without hints beyond the tag I added. This one was a bit mean, I know. ;)

Comment: I still don't understand the naturally scheming words, could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @MorganG  [Rot47](https://rot47.net/): QZQ 2?5 Q\Q 42? 36 F?2CJ WQZ}Q >62?D AøD:E:G6 }[ Q\}Q >62?D ?682E:G6 }X 3FE 42? =:<6H:D6 36 3:?2CJ WpZq[ p\qX]  q:?2CJ Z :D Qp55Q[ 3:?2CJ \ :D Q\$F3EC24EQ]  %9:D AFKK=6 FD6D E96 =6EE6CD p 2?5 \$ 2D QZQ 2?5 Q\Q[ 3FE E96D6 =6EE6CD C62==J >2<6 D6?D6 H:E9 ;FDE E96 3:?2CJ FD286Dj FD65 :? E96 F?2CJ >2??6C[ E96JVC6]]] H6==]]] C2E96C F?Q?2EFC2=]Q

Answer (score 0):

Well, a wild guess I can make:

> In the Scheming words you can remove either the first or last (but not both at the same time) letter to make another meaningful **WORD** or **EXPRESSION** used across the globe.
> Examples:
>  Given Scheming word: AREAR
>  One word formed by removing starting letter: REAR
>  Another word formed by removing last letter: AREA

And it is

> Not in the case of Non-Scheming Words. They do not satisfy either or both of the stated conditions

Comment: What about meh? Eh and me are words.

Comment: @Apep, good catch ! Any other exceptions ? :-)

Comment: Chaser is not scheming (chase)

Comment: And hence it is in Non-Scheming column @BMS21 !

Comment: REVIVE(R), CHASE(R), and GENTLE(R) are all Non-Scheming but your rule would make them Scheming.  Also, not sure how YEATSIAN would qualify as Scheming under your rule.